# div class selector with CSS

Tags: css

I would like to edit the page layout with CSS according to my div classes.  How can I select [aside[div class="one] with CSS?

**HTML:**

```
    <aside>
        <div class="one">
            <h3>What's New</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </aside>

   <aside>
        <div class="two">
            <h3>What's New</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Comment: I assume you are attempting to do something more than explained in your question, because using `.one` as the selector (as you noted in your question before you edited) will certainly select `<div class="one">`. So, what exactly did not work?

Comment: The code you've shown definitely works with `.one` as a selector: https://jsfiddle.net/3fvyr2gs/ Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. Until then, I'm voting to close the question as 'not reproducible'.

Comment: @benvc edited the question for it to make sense until closed. I made a mistake in my own code, that's why it did not work.

Comment: remove the accepted mark from the answer and you can delete the question your self

Comment: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it."

Comment: @TemaniAfif in addition to accepted answers blocking self-deletion, having two answers also blocks it. Likewise having an upvoted answer blocks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both `.one` or more securely `aside div.one`.

Here's the example for both of them:

```css
.one {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="one">
    <h3>What's New</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>

<aside>
  <div class="two">
    <h3>What's New</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

```css
aside div.one {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="one">
    <h3>What's New</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>

<aside>
  <div class="two">
    <h3>What's New</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.one` should work.

```css
.one {
background:red;
width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="one">
    <h3>What's New</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>

<aside>
  <div class="two">
    <h3>What's New</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```